# Using Multiple Stringed Ranges and Combining them into one Array

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have a script running that grabs all of the sheet names and spits it out into a column A. I took these names and then concatenated "Sheet1" with a range "!A2:D" to create a series of stringed values in column B.

```
A           B  
Sheet1        Sheet1!A2:D
Sheet2        Sheet2!A2:D
Etc.
```

I am trying to combine multiple "ranges" which are stored as strings in column B into an evaluated array. I can use "indirect" on them individually but I want to combine all of them into one giant array so I can use it in a query function.

So far I know that Arrayformula and indirect do not work. Indirect has no way of evaluating an "array" string. I have tried looking for a script that will evaluate a string but those don't seem to work.

Apart from manually creating the array, I am kinda lost now.

```
=arrayformula(If(A1:A<>"",CONCAT(A1:A,"!A2:D"),))
```

This is used to concat and create the string version of the range

I would like to be able to combine the string and have it evaluate into an array so that I can use it in a query function.

Comment: Welcome. As the current state of the question, it looks that you are asking for help to find a script but that is off-topic on this site. Please add a brief description of your efforts for writing the script by yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return a string that the built in Google Spreadsheet function can us](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56562774/how-do-i-return-a-string-that-the-built-in-google-spreadsheet-function-can-us)